# Knit file r markdown

Tags: r, dplyr

I use `filter()` to keep rows that has `upos == "PROPN"`, but the warning message tells me that I am using `filter_()`.
Here is the screen snapping :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q10wG.jpg)

Why is it so? Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to your question?

Comment: Welcome! For future questions please include your code (if possible with data to reproduce the error), not just a screenshot. This one however, is easy to answer: That's how the error message is supposed to be. You are trying to use `filter()` with a vector, that you creating by subsetting your data with `$token`in your code. Just drop that and your code should most likely work.

Comment: The problem is now gone, thanks for your concern @Nico